Chart.js 2.9.3 - Issues with time-based charts and zooming
I have a problem with chart.js 2.9.3.
The program is quite simple:

You must choose a time period
You must choose whether the X axis will be spatial (kilometers) or temporal (dates)
You must choose what to measure (speed on X, Y, Z, general temperature, CPU temperature, etc.)

Currently I have these two problems:

When the graph is spatial, the zoom works exclusively along the Y axis, the X axis remains unchanged.

When I set the graph to be temporal, I often get errors like this: "Uncaught 0 and 1708729042620 are too far apart with stepSize of 41 minute" and "Chart.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'skip')".


This is my code:
const { minTime, maxTime, intervallo } = calcolaIntervalloDati(datasets);
console.log('interval:', intervallo);
const tempoConfig = scegliUnitaTempo(intervallo);

let zoomOptions = {
    enabled: true,
    wheel: true,
    mode: 'xy',
    speed: 0.1,
    threshold: 2,
    sensitivity: 1
};

if (tempoConfig.unit === 'century' || tempoConfig.unit === 'decade') {
    zoomOptions.speed = 0.7;
} else if (tempoConfig.unit === 'year' || tempoConfig.unit === 'month') {
    zoomOptions.speed = 0.5;
} else if (tempoConfig.unit === 'day') {
    zoomOptions.speed = 0.3;
} else if (tempoConfig.unit === 'hour' || tempoConfig.unit === 'minute') {
    zoomOptions.speed = 0.2;
} else {
    zoomOptions.speed = 0.1;
}

let dataaaa = {};
let optionss = {};

console.log("minTime:", new Date(minTime).toISOString());
console.log("maxTime:", new Date(maxTime).toISOString());
console.log("optionss", optionss);
console.log("dataaaa", dataaaa);

if (selectedResolutionType == "2") { // Spatial
    dataaaa = {
        labels: datesArray,
        datasets: datasets
    };
    optionss = {                
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 0
            }
        },
        plugins: {
            zoom: {
                zoom: zoomOptions
            }
        },
    };
} else { // Temporal
    dataaaa = {
        datasets: datasets
    };   
    optionss = {                
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 0
            }
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    parser: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS',
                    unit: tempoConfig.unit,
                    stepSize: tempoConfig.stepSize,
                    displayFormats: {
                        millisecond: 'HH:mm:ss.SSS',
                        second: 'HH:mm:ss',
                        minute: 'HH:mm',
                        hour: 'HH:mm',
                        day: 'MMM D',
                        month: 'MMM yyyy',
                        year: 'yyyy',
                        decade: 'yyyy',
                        century: 'yyyy'
                    }
                },
                ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        if (tempoConfig.unit === 'decade') {
                            return value.substring(0, 3) + '0s';
                        } else if (tempoConfig.unit === 'century') {
                            return value.substring(0, 2) + '00s';
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                },
                bounds: 'data',
                min: minTime,
                max: maxTime
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                position: 'left',
                ticks: {
                    callback: (val, index, ticks) => index === 0 || index === ticks.length - 1 ? null : val,
                }
            }],
        },
        plugins: {
            zoom: {
                zoom: zoomOptions
            }
        },
    };
}

console.log("optionss", optionss);
console.log("dataaaa", dataaaa);

chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    tension: 0,
    data: dataaaa,
    options: optionss
});

// Function to determine time unit for charts
function scegliUnitaTempo(intervallo) {
    const millisecondi = intervallo;
    const secondi = millisecondi / 1000;
    const minuti = secondi / 60;
    const ore = minuti / 60;
    const giorni = ore / 24;
    const mesi = giorni / 30;
    const anni = giorni / 365;
    const decenni = anni / 10;
    const secoli = anni / 100;

    if (secoli > 2) return { unit: 'year', stepSize: Math.ceil(secoli) * 10 };
    if (decenni > 2) return { unit: 'year', stepSize: Math.ceil(decenni) };
    if (anni > 2) return { unit: 'year', stepSize: Math.ceil(anni / 5) };
    if (mesi > 2) return { unit: 'month', stepSize: Math.ceil(mesi / 5) };
    if (giorni > 2) return { unit: 'day', stepSize: Math.ceil(giorni / 5) };
    if (ore > 2) return { unit: 'hour', stepSize: Math.ceil(ore / 5) };
    if (minuti > 2) return { unit: 'minute', stepSize: Math.ceil(minuti / 5) };
    if (secondi > 2) return { unit: 'second', stepSize: Math.ceil(secondi / 5) };
    return { unit: 'millisecond', stepSize: Math.ceil(millisecondi / 5) };
}

// Function to calculate time intervals
function calcolaIntervalloDati(datasets) {
    let minTime = Infinity;
    let maxTime = -Infinity;
    
    datasets.forEach((dataset, index) => {
        console.log(`Processing dataset ${index + 1}: ${dataset.label}`);
        if (Array.isArray(dataset.data)) {
            dataset.data.forEach(point => {
                let time;
                if (typeof point === 'object' && point.x) {
                    time = new Date(point.x).getTime();
                } else if (typeof point === 'number') {
                    time = point;
                }
                if (time && !isNaN(time)) {
                    minTime = Math.min(minTime, time);
                    maxTime = Math.max(maxTime, time);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    
    console.log(`Minimum time found: ${new Date(minTime).toISOString()}`);
    console.log(`Maximum time found: ${new Date(maxTime).toISOString()}`);
    console.log(`Calculated interval: ${maxTime - minTime} ms`);
    
    return { minTime, maxTime, intervallo: maxTime - minTime };
}

I tried to modify the time unit and set it dynamically based on the collected data, but many datasets remain problematic.
I suspect the issue is due to the fact that these datasets are discontinuous: there are many temporally close data points, then a gap, and then again many temporally close data points. I need to set up a system capable of visualizing any dataset that comes from the backend, even if they were all random.
Is there a way to do this with this version of Chart.js? Using version 4.4.3, I didn't have any problems, but for performance reasons, I've been told I must use version 2.9.3.
Thank you for the help.

Why post such a lengthy and specific piece of code if it cannot at least be debugged? Please add data, canvas, and everything
else that might be missing. If your data is protected, simplify your code and add basic fake data required to
reproduce your error(s), in a minimal reproducible example.
